# How to render several barcodes with Zend 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, barcode, barcode-printing

I'm trying print several barcodes using the Zend\Barcode namespace.

The problem is reading the [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.barcode.creation.html) I can't print more than one barcode.

I can't print a echo before the barcode too.

How can I print several barcodes and texts together?

The code I'm using is similar to this one:

```
use Zend\Barcode\Barcode;

$barcodeOptions = array('text' => '123456');
$rendererOptions = array();

Barcode::render(
    'code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions
);

$barcodeOptions = array('text' => '654321');
Barcode::render(
    'code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Barcode::render()` generates an image, not an HTML page with images in it. You'll need to do something like this:

barcode.php:

```
use Zend\Barcode\Barcode;
$barcodeOptions = array('text' => $_GET['code']);
$rendererOptions = array();
Barcode::render(
    'code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions
);
```

And then in your HTML, you reference that script as if it were an image:

```
<img src="http://domain.com/barcode.php?code=123456" />
<img src="http://domain.com/barcode.php?code=654321" />
```

Comment: this work fine, thx. But can't we 'echo' the images directly?

Comment: Only if you do it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images

Comment: ˆˆ I think it is out of the scope to me. Thx a lot. Accepted =)